# How can I accept parameters in this post web api method(non-async)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to figure out how to make my webapi post operation to accept params with file upload at the same time (multipart for data)

thanks

```
public string Post()
{
    try
    {
        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        if (httpRequest.Files.Count < 1)
        {
            return "n";
        }

        foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
        {
            string downloadedImagesPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DownloadedImagesPath"];

            var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];

            var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Path.Combine(downloadedImagesPath, postedFile.FileName));
            postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "e";
    }

    return "k";
}
```

Comment: You can't have parameters on a `Multipart/Form-Data` request. What you need to do is pass in the parameters in the body of the request and parse them out. There are examples of how to do this online: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2#reading-form-control-data

Comment: thanks, make it an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have parameters on a Multipart/Form-Data request. What you need to do is pass in the parameters in the body of the request and parse them out. There are examples of how to do this here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2#reading-form-control-data

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing **HttpRequest.Form**. It is of type **NameValueCollection** and will contain form data passed through the Http request.